# waiting for an api call back to finish before calling another api in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, vuex

I have this action in vuex which basically calls two APIs. modifyResults has a call back function and I want to wait for this callback to finish then execute the updateResults. This is my setup:

//vuex

```
import {modifyResults, updateResults} from './api';
const actions = {
  async modifyResults({ dispatch }) {
    try {
      // waiting for ModifyResults to finish entirely but after
      // functionOne from api folder is finished
      // it executes updateResults from here and then executes
      // functionTwo from api folder
      await modifyResults();
      dispatch('updateResults');
    } catch (error) {
      // catch errors
    } finally {
      // loading variable set to false
    }
  },
  async updateResults({ dispatch }, ) {
    try {
      const { sources } = await updateResults();
      dispatch('setItems', sources);
    } 
    //blah blah
  },
}
```

// api.js

```
export const modifyResults = async () => {
  await functionOne({someApi},
    async functionTwo(status, resposne) => {
      const { data } = await api.post(//blah blah);
      return data
    }
  )
},
export const updateResults = async () => {
  // blah return result
},
```

So basically what happens is this is the order in which these functions are executed:

```
1- functionOne
2- updateResults
3- functionTwo
```

whereas I want this order:

```
1- functionOne
2- functionTwo
3- updateResults
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. functionOne is not shown. It's not known that it supports promises, including a callback. That you have this problem suggests that it doesn't

Comment: @EstusFlask yes it doesn't have promises, it's a simple `Stripe.card.createToken({cardInfo})` function

Comment: Docs suggests that it returns a promise https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement This is something you need to figure out. Any way, providing `async` callback is likely a mistake.